# Optimistic Lock when deleting Play! Framework

Tags: java, jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

My app is based on Play! Framework + PostgreSQL.
I can't get rid out of this optimistic lock exception, happening when I loop on a list of objects retrieved fro the database.

```
175         List<SocialAction> friendAction = SocialAction.findSocialActionsWithFieldFriendIdAndInterest
176         (interest, user);
177
178         for (SocialAction action : friendAction) {
179             action.delete();
180         }
181         
182         socialInterest.delete();
```

The exception in the browser :

```
Execution exception
[OptimisticLockException: Data has changed. updated [0] rows sql[delete from social_action where id=? and date=? and suggest_comment=? and social_interest_id=? and origin_socialaction_id=? and activity_id=? and friend_id=?] bind[null]]
In /Users/aaaaa/Documents/aaaaa-remote/app/models/SocialInterest.java at line 179.
```

In the terminal

```
play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[OptimisticLockException: Data has changed. updated [0] rows sql[delete from social_action where id=? and date is null and suggest_comment is null and social_interest_id is null and origin_socialaction_id is null and activity_id is null and friend_id is null] bind[null]]]
at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
Caused by: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Data has changed. updated [0] rows sql[delete from social_action where id=? and date is null and suggest_comment is null and social_interest_id is null and origin_socialaction_id is null and activity_id is null and friend_id is null] bind[null]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlHandler.checkRowCount(DmlHandler.java:123) ~[ebean.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DeleteHandler.execute(DeleteHandler.java:81) ~[ebean.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.execute(DmlBeanPersister.java:105) ~[ebean.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.delete(DmlBeanPersister.java:67) ~[ebean.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersistExecute.executeDeleteBean(DefaultPersistExecute.java:128) ~[ebean.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeNow(PersistRequestBean.java:535) ~[ebean.jar:na]
```

It seems the line is previously deleted from DB in a method called before this code.
But when I call findSocialActions(), it shouldn't appear in the list. So there wouldn't be an exception.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried adding 
    @Version 
    Integer version;
But it didn't avoid exceptions to be thrown. The fact is lines remain empty after a read. And I wont update them before deletion.

Comment: Whoops, it looks like you forgot to include the full exception text and your PostgreSQL version.